# Is there a way to use karma without running node?

Tags: node.js, angularjs, karma-runner

I would love to be able to test my angular application without running node. It's also ideal not to have Bower or Grunt. Does anyone know if this is possible? If so could you please point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not possible unless you port it to another language. The karma CLI is [written on Node](https://github.com/karma-runner/karma/blob/master/bin/karma).